# Render external html page with dependancies (resources)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application. In my application, I need to be able to render external HTML pages. These HTML pages are stored in a simple file structure, with images, CSS and JS files stored in folders. Basically opening the HTML file will render the page as it should be rendered. What I want is to be able to render this page programatically.

So far, I have tried stuff like this:

`Response.WriteFile(path)`

`return new FilePathResult("~/Path", "text/html");`

The problem is that the resources (images, CSS and JS files) do not get loaded, since I only load the html source.

What can I do to be able to correctly render the html file with the other included files?

P.S.: I know that this functionality can be a security hole in my application. Thanks!

**Edit**: As Darin pointed out, I can use an iframe to place the rendered HTML page in my view. This is what I am currently using, but I want to implement a more secure solution, a solution that wouldn't allow access to the actual HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to be able to correctly render the html file with the other included files?

You could use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="/somepage.html"></iframe>
```

The `return new FilePathResult("~/Path", "text/html");` should also work, it's just that the static resources referenced in this HTML page (CSS, javascript, images, ...) need to be relative to the current url or absolute urls (which is more difficult if they are static HTML).

Comment: Yes, I am currently using the iframe solution, but I would like to add some security to the access of those pages through a Controller. By making them publicly accessible, I cannot do that. The fact that the resource paths are not relative to the application is my problem. These HTML files are generated through an external tool, and the paths are just relative to the local file structure. Thanks for the answer. Will upvote.

Comment: You could serve them as static files and add a custom HTTP module to implement the security in this case.

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, will try it out and come back with an answer. Thanks again!